# PHP foreach object and change values

Tags: php

I am trying to change an object value in the following way but it doesn't work

```
<?php 
   foreach ($fields as &$field) :                   
      if($field->name == 'jform[contact_subject]'){
         $field->type = 'hidden';
      }                 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for loop and then change the values. The foreach loop doesn't allow the data to be changed from inside the loop. The for loop does